# Retour Regex to insert a new directory

Tags: regex, plugin-retour

I'm building out a new site and have moved all the existing client asset upload directories into one parent directory.

old site:

**/hero/**

**/books/**

**/slider/**

new site:

**/uploads/hero/**

**/uploads/books/**

**/uploads/slider/**

When adding a redirect in retour how can I set up a regex to catch all images/files in the various directories and point them at the new structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless absolutely everything has been moved to `/uploads/` (which is unlikely), the easiest way to do it is with 3 regex's:

`/hero/(.*)` -> `/uploads/hero/$1`

`/books/(.*)` -> `/uploads/books/$1`

`/slider/(.*)` -> `/uploads/slider/$1`

vide: [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/)